# Python Dataframe: Expand Single "Date" Column Dataframe by Adding Second Column From a List of Names To Each Date

Tags: python, dataframe, list, loops, merge

Let's say I have the following sample input dataframe below.  Please note my real table contains hundreds of dates.

| Date |
| --- |
| 2023-04-02 |
| 2023-07-14 |

The code to create above table is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':["2023-04-02","2023-07-14"]})
```

And I have a list of names:

```
names_list = ['Matthew Perry', "Amy Winehouse", "Ted Nugent"]
```

I want to expand the input table by adding a second column that contains names from the names_list.  The dates in "Date" column would get repeated until a new date is hit.

My desired output table looks like this:

| Date | Names |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-02 | Matthew Perry |
| 2023-04-02 | Amy Winehouse |
| 2023-04-02 | Ted Nugent |
| 2023-07-14 | Matthew Perry |
| 2023-07-14 | Amy Winehouse |
| 2023-07-14 | Ted Nugent |

I searched around Stack Overflow but couldn't find any code to do this.  I'm familiar with left joins and concats but I don't think either apply in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to build a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) of the names and cross-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) it with your `df` :

```
out = df.merge(pd.Series(names_list).rename("Names"), how="cross")
```

Alternatively, make a [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and pass it to the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) constructor :

```
from itertools import product

out = pd.DataFrame(
    product(df["date"], names_list), columns=["date", "Names"]
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

         date          Names
0  2023-04-02  Matthew Perry
1  2023-04-02  Amy Winehouse
2  2023-04-02     Ted Nugent
3  2023-07-14  Matthew Perry
4  2023-07-14  Amy Winehouse
5  2023-07-14     Ted Nugent
```

Comment: Using the cross merge worked!  Thank you :)  Conceptually what does cross merge do?

Comment: You're welcome ;) It creates the [cartersian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) while preserving the order of `df.date` (*here*).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, one needs to repeat names_list for len(dates_list) times and repeat each elements of dates_list for the len(names_list).

```
dates_list = ["2023-04-02","2023-07-14"]
names_list = ['A','B','C']
names_for_df = names_list*len(dates_list)
dates_for_df = [date for date in dates_list for i in range(len(names_list))]
```

However, there must be an easier pandas solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use the List for each row and then `explode` the new column:

```
df['names'] = pd.Series([names_list]* len(df))

df = df.explode('names').reset_index(drop = True)
```

gives:

```
         date          names
0  2023-04-02  Matthew Perry
1  2023-04-02  Amy Winehouse
2  2023-04-02     Ted Nugent
3  2023-07-14  Matthew Perry
4  2023-07-14  Amy Winehouse
5  2023-07-14     Ted Nugent
```